# How do I open, edit & save sharepoint documents via mobile phones?

Tags: 2010, mobile

We want the ability to Open, Edit & Save sharepoint documents primarily via Windows Phone, then later also for the other major mobile platforms: iOS, Android and Windows8 phones/tablets.

Where do I start? 
Can it be done out of the box? 
Do I need 3rd party solution & if so who is the leader in this space?

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to say you'd want to use [Office Web Applications](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps) for this. I have used it on iPads before so it should fit the bill.  [Here's](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/use-office-web-apps-on-your-android-iphone-or-windows-phone-HA010389583.aspx) an article from Microsoft specifically targeted to mobile devices.